# Rescale and reoffset in a for loop

Tags: r, lidar, lidr

I am looking for a way to run a loop to rescale and reoffset multiples laz files.

I've tried with:

```r
path <- "D:/LIDAR/UNCINATA/2020_VALDELINARES/LAZ/"
files <- list.files(path=path, pattern = "laz$")
   
for (file in 1:length(files)) {
  las <- readLAS(files[file])
  output <- las_rescale(las, xscale = 0.01, yscale = 0.01, zscale =0.01)
  writeLAS(output, paste(gsub(".laz", "_rscale.laz", basename(files[file]), fixed = TRUE)))
}
```

But I receive this error

```
Error in las_rescale(las, xscale = 0.01, yscale = 0.01, zscale = 0.01) : 
  trying to get slot "data" from an object of a basic class ("NULL") with no slots
In addition: Warning message:
In matrix(readBin(con, "raw", n = pointDataRecordLength * numberPointRecords,  :
  data length [171770257] is not a sub-multiple or multiple of the number of rows [15728225]*
```

How should I proceed?

Comment: This definitively looks like a bug that must be reported with a reproducible example. Anyway use `lastools` to rescale and reoffset in batch. lidR is subobtimal for such task as you must load in memory and write back. A general advice is: if it is part of free and open source parts of `lastools` use `lastools` instead of lidR. This include almost every task that consists in manipulating las files

Comment: You should try and narrow this down to which file is causing this. Try printing the filename out inside the loop.